# Почему программа работает в директории пользователя?

Tags: c++, linux, unix

Пытаюсь прочитать данные файла через c++. Файл лежит в одной директории с исполняемым файлом. Пишет, что файл не найден. Долго ломал голову почему так, пока не догадался проверить текущую директорию программы:

```
std::cout << "CURRENT: " << std::filesystem::current_path() << "\n";
```

Каково было мое удивление, когда оно мне вывело `CURRENT: "/Users/maksimmaltsev"`

Сама программа лежит в совершенно другой директории. Я решил проверить и поместил файл в директорию пользователя. И о чудо, программа его видит. Но разумеется меня это не устраивает. Как заставить программу считать относительные пути относительно себя, а не папки пользователя?

Если это важно:
ОС: MacOS.
Компилятор: Clang.
IDE не использую, все делаю в терминале

Comment: Важно то, где и как запускаете

Comment: В вопрос стоит добавить примеры команд сборки и запуска программы, и заодно результат работы команды `pwd`.

Comment: Это традиционное поведение во всех \*nix-ах. Так всегда было принято делать. Если требуется найти путь к каталогу (directory), где находится запущенная программа, то требуется анализировать 1) `argv[0]` (это второй аргумент в `int main (int argc, char *argv[])`) ; 2) переменную окружения `PATH` (в ней через `:` перечислены каталоги в которых происходит поиск запускаемой программы, если в аргументе ее вызова (тот самый `argv[0])`) нет символов `/`)

Comment: @avp Для линукса однострочник есть: `std::filesystem::canonical("/proc/self/exe")`. Я бы поискал какой-то системный вызов для этого, руками доставать из argv и PATH - гиблое дело.

Comment: Как найти путь к исполняемому файлу на разных платформах: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1024937/9047589

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, почему гиблое? Пишите один раз полсотни строк на Си и пользуетесь далее

Comment: @avp `/proc/self/exe` никогда не сломается, а про самописное решение я не уверен. Для начала, в `argv[0]` же можно любой мусор прислать.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, не во всех \*nix-ах есть /proc ... (кстати, ТС работает в MacOS) (что же касается самописного -- с чего это вы так не уверены в себе?)

Comment: @avp Я думаю вы поняли мысль. Там куча мелочей; это мало написать, нужно еще кучей тестов обложить. Какой разделитель в PATH, `;` или `:`. Что делать с пустыми путями в PATH. Где взять `argv[0]` в гуевом приложении под MSVC, если там `WinMain` вместо `main()`. Оно все равно все будет в `#ifdef`-ах, а если уж обкладываться `#ifdef`-ами, то имхо лучше сразу использовать штатные средства ОС (на линуксе - однострочник, на винде - [почти однострочник](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulefilenamea), на макоси тоже что-то должно быть).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, про винду я ничего не говорил -- не пишу для них